# Unable to connect to Google BigQuery using Mule

Tags: google-bigquery, mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I am trying to connect to BigQuery for migrating data and I am currently facing some issues in connection.

2 approaches which I am currently focusing on

1. **Database Connector** with passing JDBC connection string

```
<db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="07671c43-86bc-4768-b914-c71058120615" >
    <db:generic-connection url="jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=<project-id>;OAuthType=0;OAuthPvtKeyPath=<path-to-key-file>;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=<email>" driverClassName="com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver"/>
</db:config>
```

The above results in an error when testing connection

```
ToolingException{message='Got status code: 500 when trying to
 resolve a Mule Runtime operation. Reason: 'Server Error.
 {"errorType":null,"errorMessage":null,"errorDetail":null,"additionalProperties":{servlet=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-7bf5036,
 message=Request failed.,
 url=/mule/tooling/applications/4cfe61fc-a304-4ee5-8b52-36ed6e4cfd66/components/Database_Config/connection,
 status=500}}''   , rootCauseMessage='null'   , rootCauseType='null'  
 , rootCauseStackTrace='[]'}    at
 org.mule.tooling.client.api.exception.ToolingException$Builder.build(ToolingException.java:141)
    at
 org.mule.tooling.agent.rest.client.RestAgentToolingService.handleToolingAgentHandlerException(RestAgentToolingService.java:911)
    at
 org.mule.tooling.agent.rest.client.RestAgentToolingService.lambda$serviceExceptionOrToolingException$43(RestAgentToolingService.java:859)
    at
 org.mule.tooling.agent.rest.client.RestAgentToolingService.serviceExceptionOr(RestAgentToolingService.java:873)
```

2. **BigQuery Connector** provided by MuleSoft

```
    <bigquery:config name="BigQuery__Configuration" doc:name="BigQuery  Configuration" doc:id="3b8287ed-f3e5-4721-bd9e-96950347cf3a" >
        <bigquery:jwt-connection privateKeyId="<private-key-id>" privateKey="<private-key>" issuer="<email>" projectId="<project-id>" />
    </bigquery:config>
```

The above results in an error

```
 org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not
 create connection   Caused by:
 org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Invalid PKCS8
 data.
```

I made sure the credentials passed are appropriate and we also checked with the customer regarding appropriate privileges to use this but still did not find a way to solve this.

**References**

[mulesoft-bigquery-jdbc](https://apisero.com/mulesoft-bigquery-series-3/)